# Express and Pug: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Im trying to make a registration form that displays errors if an input is invalid. I am using express.js and pug to do it.
Here's my JavaScript:

```js
const express = require("express");
const pug     = require("pug");

const app     = express();
const port    = 8001;
const dir     = __dirname;

app.use(express.static(`${dir}/static`));
app.set("views", `${dir}/pug`);
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.get("/community/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render(`${dir}/pug/community/register.pug`, { 
        "emailErr": false,
        "usernameErr": false,
        "passwordErr": false
    });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And here's my pug

```pug
extends common.pug 

block title 
    title Register 

block header 
    h1 Register 

block content 
    form(name="register" action="register.php" method="post")
        table 
            tr 
                td 
                    label E-mail 
                td 
                    input(name="email" type="email" required)
            tr 
                td(colspan="2" class="err-text")
                    if _emailErr
                        p This E-mail is taken.
            tr 
                td 
                    label Username 
                td 
                    input(name="username" type="text" required)
            tr 
                td(colspan="2" class="err-text") 
                    if _usernameErr 
                        p This username is taken.
            tr 
                td 
                    label Password 
                td 
                    input(name="password" type="password" required)
            tr
                td(colspan="2" class="err-text")
                    if _passwordErr 
                        p The passwords do not match.
            tr 
                td 
                    label Confirm Password 
                td 
                    input(name="confirm_password" type="password" required)
            tr
                td(colspan="2") 
                    p By registering, you agree to the #[a(href="privacy-policy") privacy policy].
        input(type="submit" value="Register")
        p Already have an account? #[a(href="login") Login here]
```

I have also tried other variations like `pug.renderFile` or putting the messages directly into the variables. But every time (in this particular project only) I get this error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Function (<anonymous>)
    at wrap (D:\directory\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10)
    at Object.exports.compile (D:\directory\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:289:7)
    at handleTemplateCache (D:\directory\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:242:25)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\directory\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:454:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\directory\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:444:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (D:\directory\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:493:11)
    at View.render (D:\directory\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\directory\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\directory\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
```

This also occurs in the remote server where I host it. However, this does *not* occur in a different project on my computer, which looks something like this:

```js
const pug = require("pug");

console.log(pug.renderFile("test.pug", {
    name: "Foo"
}))
```

```pug
p #{name}
```

and it worked perfectly fine.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Heres base.pug (common.pug extends this)

```pug
doctype html 
html(lang="en")
    head 
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        link(rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="style.css")
        link(href="lib/prism/prism.css" rel="stylesheet")
        script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js")
        script(src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/imightwanttohidethis.js" crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src="lib/prism/prism.js")
        block title 
    body 
        .head-heading
            .head-left 
                h1
                    a(href="./") LOGO
        .navbar 
            .head-icon 
                i.fas.fa-bars 
            block navbar
            script(src="nav.js")
        .body 
            .body-textbox 
                .body-textbox-content
                    div 
                        block header 
                        block content
            footer.footer 
                .footer-content
                    .footer-logo
                        a(href="./")
                            img(src="./logo.png" alt="logo")
                        p copyright thing
                    .footer-links
                        p 
                            a(href="/privacy-policy") Privacy Policy 
                        p 
                            a(href="/sitemap") Sitemap 
                        p 
                            a(href="/acknowledgements") Acknowledgements
```

and here's common.pug

```pug
extends ../base.pug

block navbar 
    ul
        li 
            a(href="./insert") insert
        li 
            a(href="./links") links
        li 
            a(href="./here") here
        li 
            a.active(href="./community") Community
```

These also work fine with pugs without parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure you need `${dir}/pug` in your `res.render` function as you already specified your view folder : `app.set("views", \`${dir}/pug\`);`